# Are unused CSS images downloaded?

Tags: css

Are unused CSS images downloaded by the browser or ignored?

Eg. in CSS rules which don't match any elements.

```
.nothingHasThisClass{background:url(hugefile.png);}
```

Or would this be browser-dependant?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

This would be browser dependent, since it's how they decide to implement the spec, however in a quick test here:

- Chrome: **Doesn't**
- FireFox: **Doesn't**
- Safari: **Doesn't**
- IE8: **Doesn't**
- IE7: **Doesn't**
- IE6: *Unknown* (Can someone test and comment?)

Comment: I'm assuming that you've tested on Windows? If you'd like to add cross-platform comparisons then I can offer that Firefox 3.6.x and Chrome 5.0.307.11 (Ubuntu 9.10) also **don't**. =)

Comment: Aha, I see. I thought it would be quite poor for firefox, chrome and safari to load them, but I wouldn't have put it past IE. Is this result the same for IE 6 and 7?

Comment: @Alex - IE7 Yes, though a more complex page might trick it?  IE6 I can't test where I am...maybe someone here can and update my answer.

Comment: Can I file a protest against testing anything in IE6?

Comment: @Dave - I'm not sure anyone will test and comment...if so I'll update.  Since there's an unspoken requirement of bleaching your eyes after looking at IE6......

Comment: Sadly, some people just can't let their beloved IE6 go (about 20%).

Comment: @Dave: Everything should be tested in IE6 (the unFaithful departed) , if it runs correctly there, and it will in every goddamn browser :P

Comment: I don't think anyone wants to test it in IE6 because that would require them *admitting* they still use it.

Answer (score 13):

No, they are not downloaded, not at least in Firefox, IE8 and Chrome.

An easy way to test this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css">
        .nonexistent {
            background: url('index.php?foo');
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php if(isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
} ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If `test.txt` is populated with the browser's user agent, then the image is downloaded. This was not the case in any of my tests.

Answer (score 9):

A quick test proved it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css"><!--

.hasnothing{background-image:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ky7aakqvH01qatluqo1_400.jpg);}
.hassomething{background-image:url(http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kxytwr7YzH1qajh4xo1_500.png);}

--></style>

</head><body>

<div class="hassomething"></div>

</body></html>
```

The 2nd image, `tumblr_kxytwr7YzH1qajh4xo1_500.png`, was downloaded but not the other one. This was proven true in Chrome (Developer tools) and Firefox (Firebug).

Answer (score 8):

Firefox and Chrome (Ubuntu 9.10) don't download images for classes/ids that aren't applied in the DOM.

This may be both platform *and* browser dependant, though.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, it depends just exactly what "unused" means. Different browsers define it differently.  For example, in Firefox, styles applied to the `<noscript>` tag are deemed "unused" and thusly, any images won't be downloaded.

Chrome 26 (possibly all of them, not sure), **does** download CSS images if they are applied to the `<noscript>` element, even when JS is enabled. (It isn't immediately clear to me why though, perhaps this is a bug?).

It **does not** download CSS images applied to elements *within* the `<noscript>` element, though. (this is expected behaviour, of course).

#### Example:

CSS:

```
noscript { background-image: url('always.png') 0 0 repeat; }
noscript p ( background-image: url('nojsonly.png') 0 0 repeat; }
```

HTML:

```
<noscript>The CSS background image of this NOSCRIPT-element will always be downloaded in Chrome.  Will not be downloaded in Firefox</noscript>
<noscript><p>The CSS background image of this P-element won't be downloaded in Chrome or other browsers, unless JS is disabled</p></noscript>
```

In this case, if the user has JS-enabled, **both** always.png and otherbg.png are downloaded in Chrome.  If the user does *not* have JS enabled, then only nojsonly.png is downloaded in Chrome.

I use this technique for measuring traffic-levels from non-JS-enabled users, as Google Analytics fails us here.  I prefer using the background CSS image rather than a normal `<img...>` tag, because I'm working under the (untested) theory that bots are less likely to grab a CSS image than a `<img...>` image, leaving more accurate counts for the human-visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all browsers do lazy-loading. If an image is not required, it does not download. Use firebug (add-on in Firefox/Chrome) to see load time for resources.

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, though, Chrome (at least) will download unused.png in the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .unused {
                background: url(unused.png) no-repeat;
            }
            .used {
                background: url(used.png);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="unused used">
            hello world
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that's because it's referenced.  So I'm not sure calling it "unused" is really valid..

Comment: @eentzel, please remove "unused" from the div, redo the test and tell us your result.