# Website with HTML5 (Stepcarousel) slow in IE?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, internet-explorer

Please look at this page in IE and Chrome/Firefox: http://goo.gl/kR2Cv

In Chrome/Firefox it loads quickly and works fine, but in Internet Explorer it loads slow and is very laggy. In the page I use HTML5 and jquery/stepcarousel with alot of images. The whole site is just one html-page.

What I dont understand is why it works so good in Chrome/Firefox but not in Internet Explorer? Someone who can point that out to me and maybe help me with a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer had a notoriously atrocious engine before version 9. In addition to lagging well behind in support for modern standards, it was very slow as well. Versions 9 and above, however, have improved significantly, and as a result, your website runs similarly smoothly in IE9, Firefox and Chrome. However, in IE8, it runs extremely slowly as you say.

If you want to support IE8, perhaps you can fall back on a less effects-heavy design just for those users, to keep performance optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thought it could be something like that. Since the website works fine in IE9 and all other browsers I consider this problem not that important and is going to drop it.

Answer (score 1):

Your site is **way** too heavy. It's nearing 3mb, takes 12s to load on Chrome (10mbps connection). You should avoid downloading all those background pictures until they are needed, and optimize the hell out of them (use ImageOptim, PunyPNG or similar, you'll have to sacrifice a little quality for JPEGs). Aim for <600kb on the home page.

Older IE versions have lower parallel download limits than modern browsers, and are probably choking on the amount of images loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to optimize the images.

Comment: I have tried to optimize them more but they look like sh*t when I do that. So I changed them back. The images are pretty optimized as it is. The problem is that there are 36 images (90-130kB each) that have to load when you enter the site.

So do you know how I can make the background pictures dont load until they are needed?

Comment: @StreamAlex keep them off the HTML, and add them via javascript (using css classes or data-* attributes) when you go to the relevant section. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded

Answer (score 0):

With my slow connection FF loaded the page ten times faster than IE9. I think you have a problem with the fileformat. The code below is a snippet from your code:

`klÃ¤der fÃ¶r dam och barn, frÃ¥n idÃ©`

Make sure you save the file in `DOS/Windows` or `ANSI`-mode.

Comment: I will try to do that. Can you please remove the line from the website from your post too? I don't want that to be picked up from Google. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of HTML for IE8 to be moving around all at the same time. That's it's a table layout probably doesn't help. Tables tend to trigger a lot more reflow calculation.

Lots of good advice on the subject here:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/