# CSS Background Image loading always?

Tags: css

I have a class defined in my styles.css as:

```
.caquote {background: url("http://cdn.domain.com/images/quotebig.png") no-repeat 10px 8px ;}
```

Will the image still be loaded by modern browsers if on the html page I don't define `.caquote` anywhere?

Comment: This should be easy to check by making page that includes `styles.css` but not that particular class. Load that page into your browser and watch the network traffic (using "Developer Tools" in Chrome or "Web Console" in Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are unused CSS images downloaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded)

Answer (score 2):

The images of a css are download only if they are used in the HTML : 
I have made an example for you in a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b3QXu/
As you can see, the second image is load only when you hover the div. If you don't hover the div, the image will not be downloaded by your computer.

```
#bonjour {
background-image : url(http://rosalienebacchus.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/planet-earth-from-space.jpg);
width : 500px;
height : 500px;
background-color : #123456;
background-size : cover;
}

#bonjour:hover {
    background-image : url(http://www.desktopas.com/files/2013/06/Outer-Space-Moon-    Earth-Spaceman.jpg);
}
```

For your information : All images on a HTML file are load, even if they are set as display:none on css.

Comment: Damien your answer says the opposite of @ceqfault   - who is correct ?

Comment: I'm sure of my answer :) Have you try my jsfiddle ? You see clearly that the second image is not load until you hover the div. Even if this image is declared in the css. important : clear you cache before retesting !

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern browsers (IE7 and newer). [It has been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded).

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the two answers as contradictory. 
Damien says the background-image property that loads an image is invoked only when it's used.
In his hover example, the image wasn't needed *until* the hover event.

cegfault says that the images are loaded even in a display:none.
He also says that that the page can display (as enough elements are calculated and rendered), and *then* [once it has downloaded in parallel] the background image will appear. That doesn't mean that the bg image was blocked. Just that it was so big that it took a while to download.