# What is the most efficient way to have background images of different sizes in a responsive design website?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a responsive website. This website needs a lot of background images (both vector and raster formats).

I want to optimize the website for loading speed but not decrease picture quality.

My understanding is that I should have different versions for the same picture so that for small window devices the user automatically downloads the correct smallest file size.

My question is: What is the best way to deal with this problem? Do I need to use media queries? how to use them such that different browsers actually don't download unnecessary data?

Comment: is that what you want? demo - http://jsfiddle.net/antcnf14/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, another post here on SO discussed if an unused css image `url('');` is downloaded by the browser even if no element matches the rule. And it's been tested and established that on all major browsers, the images won't be downloaded *unless an element actually matches the selector*.

Post: [Are unused CSS images downloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded)

It means that, if you define media queries for your styles, only the images inside rules that match the specific viewport will be downloaded.

In the following example, if you're in a device which is 480px wide or less, don't worry because `large.jpg` won't be downloaded.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #myDiv {
        background-image: url('small.jpg');
    }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
    #myDiv {
        background-image: url('large.jpg');
    }
}
```

Just reminding that this is a behavior left up to the browsers, so they can change anytime they want.