# deferred CSS background image (or font) files

Tags: javascript, css, image, asynchronous, deferred-loading

I want to load CSS background images **asynchronously in a non-blocking way**.

I can see in Chrome that if I put the image into a class and load the image by adding the class to the DOM element, it works. Demo:

```
setTimeout(function(){$("#imageContainer").addClass("imageClass");},10000);
```

The network monitor shows that the actual image file is **only loaded when the class is applied**.

However, I imagine the browser might as well already load the image file when it loads the CSS (which would probably block rendering).

Question:

**Does the standard demand that the image file is only loaded when the class is applied?**

I am sorry I wouldn't even know where to start looking for this detail.

**Addendum**: same question goes for **font files**, too! If a fancy font is part of one class and the class is applied asynchronously - will the font file also be loaded asynchronously?

Comment: The browser will only read/render the css styles once the selector rule is met... So, an image loaded with `url()` will only be downloaded once an element meets the selector containing this rule

Comment: http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/loading-css-asynchronously/7104

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_background.html

Comment: Thanks @LcSalazar! Do you have a source for this assertion? If so - that would be the answer to this question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are unused CSS images downloaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396909/are-unused-css-images-downloaded)

Comment: This does indeed look like sort of a duplicate, and I guess I'll have to go with heuristics then. Thanks!